# Find function based on relation between partial derivatives and a few constraints

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm looking for a function $f(x, y)$ in the domain $0 < x, y \le 1$ and range $0 < f(x, y) \le 1$ such that:
1. $\frac{\partial f / \partial y}{\partial f / \partial x} = a\cdot \frac{y}{x}$ for some positive constant $a$
2. $f(1, 1) = 1$

I've tried guessing at the partial derivatives and integrating, but all of those attempts resulted in a function that either violates the other constraint or the function's range. For example setting $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = ay, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = x$ leads to:
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = ay \Rightarrow f(x,y) = \frac{ay^2}{2} + c_1(x) + c $
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = x \Rightarrow f(x,y) = \frac{x^2}{2} + c_2(y) + c $
Therefore $f(x,y) = \frac{x^2 + ay^2}{2} + c$ which for large values of $a$ easily violates the function's range.

The tricky thing for me is that there are infinitely many possible guesses for the partial derivatives that contain some common factor which cancels out when dividing $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ by $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$.

I don't know if there's a rigorous way of doing this or it's just guesswork, or if this is even possible at all. So general suggestions for handling the situation would be very helpful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x,y)=e^{\frac {x^{2}+ay^{2}} 2} e^{-\frac {1 +a} 2}$ has all the properties you need.